# AFOpenFlow coverFlow

Tags: iphone

in the AFOpenFlow library are two lines that says that the coverFlow is in the middle of your
iPhone - Screen:

```
CGPoint newPosition;

 newPosition.x = halfScreenWidth + aCover.horizontalPosition;
 newPosition.y = halfScreenHeight + aCover.verticalPosition;
```

But how could i change this line, that the coverFlow at the high range of the screen?

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know AFOpenFlow but this math here set the middle of the View related to the center of the screen.  If you want the view to only take half of the size of your screen, you also need to change its height.  it would be like :

**[Updated Code]**

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, swcreenHeight/2);
CGPoint newCenterPosition = CGPointMake(halfScreenWidth+aCover.horizontalPosition, halfScreenHeight/2+aCover.verticalPosition)

aCover.bounds = CGRectMake(newCenterPosition.x, newCenterPosition.y, newSize.width, newSize.height);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it don't works 100% correctly, the coverFlow is higher, but not at the top of the screen, and the last line didn't works, because illegal argument?